# I can't create doubly linked list properly in C

Tags: c

My list head always points to tail. What's the problem?

My `linked_list.h`:

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST
#define LINKED_LIST

struct node 
{
    char *data;
    struct node *nextElement;
    struct node *prevElement;
};

void createList(struct node **head, struct node **tail);
void fill_list (char *word, struct node **head, struct node **tail);

#endif
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <string.h>

int main()
{   
    FILE *dataFile; 
    char *word = (char *) calloc ( 255, sizeof(char) );

/* Create empty list */
    struct node *head, *tail;     
    createList (&head, &tail);
/*------------------------*/

/* Data file open*/
   dataFile = fopen("data.txt" ,"r");  
   if( dataFile == NULL )
   {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

/* Data reading */
    while (( fscanf(dataFile, "%s", word) ) != EOF )
    {
      int i          = 0;
      int wordsCount = 0;

      for (i = 0; i <= strlen(word); i++)
      {
         if ( (word[i] >= 'a') && (word[i] <= 'z') )
            wordsCount = wordsCount + 1;
      }

      if ( wordsCount == strlen(word) )
      {
        fill_list ( word, &head, &tail );   
      }     
    }

   fclose(dataFile);
   return 0;
};
```

and `linked_list.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linked_list.h"

void createList(struct node **head, struct node **tail) 
{
    *head = NULL;
    *tail = NULL; 
}

void fill_list ( char *word,        struct node **head,     struct node **tail )
{
    struct node *elem, *temp;

    if ( (*head) == NULL )
    {
    //  printf("HEAD = NULL\n");

        elem = (struct node *) malloc ( sizeof (struct node) );
        elem -> data = word;
        elem -> nextElement = NULL;
        elem -> prevElement = NULL;
        (*head) = elem;
        *tail = elem;   
    //  printf("%s\n", (*head)  -> data  );         
    }
    else
    {
    //  printf("HEAD != NULL\n");
        elem = (struct node *) malloc ( sizeof (struct node) );
        elem -> data = word;
        elem -> nextElement = NULL;
        elem -> prevElement = *tail;
        *tail = elem;
    //  printf("%s\n", (*head)  -> data  );         
    }
}
```

My data file: qw erty b cc. 
Firstly, `head == NULL`, so `head -> data = 'qw'`  and it should be as head all the time, but it changes to erty, then b and cc after every loop step.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't making sure the old last element points to the new last element when you add an element to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use the same string for all input, and you use that for all nodes. This means *all* nodes will have its `data` member point to the same string. This string will of course only contain what you last read into it.

You may want to keep the string buffer in `main` as a normal array (instead of allocating it on the heap) and use e.g. [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) to duplicate the string for the nodes. Don't forget to free them later though.

---

A pointer is exactly what it sounds like, it's a variable that *points* to some other place in memory. You can have many pointers all pointing to the same memory.

In your case you pass the pointer `word` in the function `main` to all our calls to `fill_list`. This means that all nodes you create in `fill_list` will use the exactly same pointer, and they will all point to the exact same memory.

This means that all nodes in your list will have the `data` member seem to be the same value and it will always be the last string read into `word` in the `main` function.

If you use a function such as `strdup` it will *duplicate* the string. I.e. it will allocate completely new memory for the string and copy from the old area into the newly allocate area, and return a pointer to the newly allocated memory.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, please?
I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: @Pauliuks Elaborated a little.

Comment: Okay, now the main question is how to use strdup.
Where and how I should use it? Sorry for dumb questions, but maybe it doesn't take a lot of time to you.

Comment: @Pauliuks `elem->data = strdup(word);` It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 void fill_list ( char *word,        struct node **head,     struct node **tail )
    {
        struct node *elem, *temp;

        /* you need to create node first !  */
        elem = (struct node *) malloc ( sizeof (struct node));
        elem -> data = NULL ;
        elem -> data = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char)*255));
        if ( elem -> data == NULL )
          {
             perror("alloc data failed ");

          }

        if ( (*head) == NULL )
        {
        //  printf("HEAD = NULL\n");
    /* call memcpy() function need to #include <string.h> */

            elem -> data = memcpy((void*)elem -> data,(void*)word,strlen(word));
            elem -> nextElement = NULL;
            elem -> prevElement = NULL;
            (*head) = elem;
            *tail = elem;   
        //  printf("%s\n", (*head)  -> data  );         
        }
        else
        {
        //  printf("HEAD != NULL\n");

            elem -> data = memcpy((void*)elem -> data,(void*)word,strlen(word));
            elem -> nextElement = NULL;
            elem -> prevElement = *tail;
            *tail = elem;
        //  printf("%s\n", (*head)  -> data  );         
        }
```

Comment: Program crashes after:   
/* alloc for the each node */
elem -> data = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char)*255 );